# Does the Leprechaun o'Fyffe exist in the 3DS version of terraria?

Tags: terraria-console

The reason is because i'm unsure on if the rainbow pieces are even in that version at all.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/St._Patrick%27s_Day), the St. Patrick's Day update was released on Android (1.1.92) and iOs (1.1.9) only.